# Does there exist any free software to play multichannel WAV on macOS

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, audio, midi

I'm trying to play a 4-channel WAV to 4 speakers (L&R of 2 USB soundcards).

It is [possible](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202000) to use `Audio MIDI Setup` app to create an aggregate output device.

Supposing I have such a .WAV file, how to go about playing it?

Comment: Does the QuickTime app not work?

Comment: Audacity, VLC, and QuickTime should all suffice. Audacity should be the easiest to test your setup — provided you have correctly set up your aggregate output device, you can just select it directly in Audacity and test playback.